# Keep data for unchecked option from checkbox d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, filter

I'm really struggling linking the checked/unchecked to lines.

I managed to have lines selected when options checked from checkbox.
But when the options are unchecekd then they are removed completely. 
Instead of removing them, I'd to like to have them chinging attributes, such as colours.

I took the relevant part only since original code is unnessesarily long. 
The data is nested by key - country and the checkbox options contain the country as id/value.

Initially lines (same path but grey colour) are rendered and the part below is colouring the lines that are selected in the checkbox.

Lines are coloured successfully but they disappear when the respective options are unchecekd. Instead, I'd like to have them remain with initial colour which is grey.

But it seems .exit() doesn't work here. 
I'm really struggling... Could anyone help me?

```
d3.select(#checkbox).on("change", function() { 

    var country = this.value
        display = this.checked ? "inline" : "none"; 

    var filtered = lineWrapper
                    .selectAll(".line")
                    .filter(function(d) { return d.key === country; });

    filtered
        .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
            .style("stroke",  function(d) {return colScale(d.key); })
            .style("stroke-width", 3)
            .style("fill", "none");

    filtered
        .exit()
        .transition()
            .style("stroke", "#C0C0C0")
            .style("stroke-width", 1)
            .style("fill", "none");
```

Comment: Are you able to post a working example?

Comment: you have not used `.data()` so `.exit()` is useless? Your question is not clear what you want to do "the part below is colouring"(???). What do you tink `.exit()` does?

Comment: @rioV8 Sorry I was a bit in a hurry. So, I rendered an intial chart with grey lines. The part that I posted is intended, when an option (a country) in checkbox is selected, then the line is coloured according to colScale (which isn't included in the part). If the option is unchecked, the line should come back to initial grey colour. But istead, the current code removes lines for unchecked option completely. Does it make sense?

Comment: in the callback that sets the `stroke` color just add an `if` that based on `checked` set the color to `grey` or `colScale()`, you can use the `?:` operator `d => checked ? colScale(d.key) : "#C0C0C0"`

Comment: @rioV8 Thank you so much for the reply. It's really a way to go! How can I state the if condition with checekd? I tried with "this.checked" but it threw an error that it was unrecheable.

Comment: the `this` in the callback will be the correct one if you use an arrow function, otherwise create a var that stores the value of `this.checked`

Comment: @rioV8, thanks so much. It works well. So far, I've used .filter() only to filter data not for selection like this occasion. Would you mind expalining when do you choose to use selection.filter()? instead of .enter() / .exit()? filter and enter/exit may not be supplementary but I was wondering in which cases .filter can be benefitial.

Comment: @MIke: `enter/exit` are used in `join` read the docs, `filter` is to change the selection

Comment: @rioV8, thanks for the hint. I now understand what was missing. Thanks a lot!